# How to fix out of memory error when comparing 5 million records in two files using Perl in windows environment

Tags: perl

I'm comparing two files of 5 million records each(each lines contains so many columns but I need to compare only 2 columns). any better approach to compare two files and find the differences without out of memory error?

I have tried parsing each file into different hashes and comparing both hashes leads to out of memory error.

Comment: Could you please give us some more details? Post some of your code (the smallest part that works) and tell us what format the files are in.

Comment: Don't load the entire file into memory but only chunks of it. First thing that comes into my mind is [Tie::File](https://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html). Quote "The file is not loaded into memory, so this will work even for gigantic files.".

Comment: Another good approach is to load only one file into memory and then go through the other file line by line. If both files are sorted by the key columns, you don't even need to load either file into memory and can simply march line by line through both files.

Comment: @sticky bit, That's horrible advice. Tie::File uses as much memory as loading the loading the entire file into memory into memory, and it takes 30x longer.

Comment: @ikegami: So the documentation lies? Good to know...

Comment: @stickybit, It keeps an index of every line encountered. If your file has a lot of short lines (e.g. source code), T::F will end up using more memory. For files with a lot a long lines, you'll get savings, but it'll still use a ton of memory

Answer (score 1):

The first question is, do you need to be using Perl to begin with?

Have you thought about using standard Linux utilities?

Depending on how your columns of data are constructed and delimited, there is a very good chance that Linux 'cut' could work for you to extract from each file only the column you need into a temp file.

Then use Linux 'sort' to sort each temp file.

Then use Linux 'diff' or 'comm' to compare the two temp files.

None of the above-suggested utilities should have any out-of-memory issues even on two files of 5 million records, assuming you have a reasonable amount of memory and disk space (e.g., for 'sort' to create its own temporary files).